# Scroll to a special div by click on a location pin in map from google

Tags: html, asp.net, dictionary

I have a map in my website from google map. It shows places registered in Unesco. I want to Scroll in a Special div in the Page by clicking on the location in map but all of them have the same class name? any recommendation? Thank you all

Comment: Please provide some code samples to understand more

Comment: It's may Jcode:  
$('#Yazd').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.heritage-left ul li').eq(19).offset().top - 170
        }, 1000)

    });


It works but by clicking on a div. I want to do it by clicking on a lacation in map embeded in my site. Hope to Understand my mean

Comment: check this if it is helpful https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpoqPK

Comment: There is limited event handlings for map. check this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

Comment: Thank you and apologize for answering so late. I solved my problem by using another way. I couldn't do something that Ireally wanted, Unfortunately. and about the link you shred, It works just for a marker. I have alot of markers!!